# ExtJS Architect : Is it wise to split a big application across multiple projects?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm starting to build a rather big application in ExtJS Architect and I was wondering if it is advisable to split the application into multiple projects (to be precise projects as Architect defines a project)?

At the moment I am the only engineer working on this application, however more engineers may be assigned in the future. What would be the points to consider if you would to like to split up the project in smaller pieces or build one big project?

In addition: as far as I know it is not possible to 'share' a project in Architect over more than one developer. That votes in favor for splitting the project.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not used Architect to build a project. 
My thought on the matter is that if you are building an MVC project and you want Architect to manage your controllers and views you should keep all of it together. Especially if you have cross cutting communications between modules. However if you are 100% certain that your modules are completely standalone - meaning they have nothing to do with one another and might as well be separate apps ... (maybe they should?) ... then you could build them out separately  and weave them back together after you are ready to ditch the architect. Remember its a one way street not an IDE. Bringing the modules together should just mean that the app.js now lists all of your controllers for all modules instead of just one for your module.